# CREATOR object to be static on class com.example.android.movieapp.Movie

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

When I try to send an object to another `Activity`, it shows this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.movieapp/com.example.android.movieapp.DetailActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires the CREATOR object to be static on class com.example.android.movieapp.Movie
```

This is my code:

```
public class Movie implements Parcelable{
String title;
String image;

public Movie (String title, String image){
    this.title = title;
    this.image = image;
}

public Movie(JSONObject movie) throws JSONException {
    this.title = movie.getString("original_title");
    this.image = movie.getString("poster_path");

}

private Movie (Parcel in){
    title = in.readString();
    image = in.readString();
}

public final Parcelable.Creator<Movie> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Movie>(){

    @Override
    public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
        return new Movie(parcel);
    }

    @Override
    public Movie[] newArray(int i) {
        return new Movie[i];
    }
};

@Override
public String toString() {
    return title + "--" + image;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeString(image);
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
```

}

Main Class:

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Movie movie = movieAdapter.getItem(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("send", movie);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

and DetailClass:

```
Movie movie;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        movie  = extras.getParcelable("send");
        title.setText(movie.title);
```

Comment: public static final Parcelable.Creator<Movie> CREATOR = ...

Answer (score 3):

The exception states:

> ...the CREATOR object to be static on class com.example.android.movieapp.Movie

Also, from the [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) documentation:

> Classes implementing the Parcelable interface must also have a non-null static field called CREATOR of a type that implements the Parcelable.Creator interface.

`CREATOR` has to be static:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Movie> CREATOR =
```